# creating dropdown from php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array(             
        [attribute_name] => Brand             
        [attribute_value] => Lee         
    )      
    [1] => Array(
         [attribute_name] => Brand  
         [attribute_value] => Levis         
    )      
    [2] => Array( 
        [attribute_name] => Brand    
        [attribute_value] => Raymond         
    )      
    [3] => Array( 
        [attribute_name] => Fabric 
        [attribute_value] => Cotton         
    )   
    [4] => Array(
        [attribute_name] => Fabric  
        [attribute_value] => Linen         
    )  
)
```

I want to create two drop down from this array one is for `Brand` which should have three options and another one is for `fabric` which should have two option.

I can do simply by checking `attribute_name` is `brand` or `fabric`, but this is not static there can be anything instead of `brand` and `fabric`.

I've tried so many things but not worked. Please help me in doing this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of structure, you must first create a grouping array out of your data first. So that in turn, they'll be easier to manage. First, group all of them by using a loop, using attribute name as keys, pushing the values. Will look something like this:

```
// grouping
$grouped = array();
foreach($array as $values) {
    $grouped[$values['attribute_name']][] = $values['attribute_value'];
}
```

This loop would create such structure:

```
Array
(
    [Brand] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lee
            [1] => Levis
            [2] => Raymond
        )

    [Fabric] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cotton
            [1] => Linen
        )

)
```

After they are grouped. Then comes the presentation:

Use this as an idea:

```
<form method="POST">
<?php foreach($grouped as $label => $values): ?>
    <label><?php echo $label; ?></label>
    <select name="select_values[<?php echo $label; ?>]">
        <?php foreach($values as $value): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select><br/><br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<br/><input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then once you submit the form, just handle it like you normally would. Assign it so some variable.

```
if(!empty($_POST['select_values'])) {
    $selected = $_POST['select_values'];
    echo '<pre>', print_r($selected, 1), '</pre>';
}
```

This would look like this after selections have been made:

```
Array
(
    [Brand] => Lee
    [Fabric] => Cotton
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$filteredArray = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === 'Brand' || $key === 'Fabric') {
        array_push($filteredArray, $value);
    }
}
```

$filteredArray now contains only Brand and Fabric.

Comment: Please understand the question before giving the answer. $key will give me 0 1 2 3 4 not brand and fabric